# django channels cannot authenticate user using django inbuilt authentication system as mentioned in documents

Tags: python, django, django-channels, django-login

I want to run a consumer which requires authenticated user in my channels application 
channels disconnecting the consumer saying that user isn't authenticated

but the user is authenticated and  his cookies are updated in the browser

I have followed channels documentation which authenticates user

```
class LikeConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):

        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        # user = self.scope['user']
        user=self.user
        print(user)

        if user.is_anonymous:
            await self.close()
            print("user is anonymous")
        else:
            await self.accept()
            # user_group = await self._get_user_group(self.scope['user'])

            await self.channel_layer.group_add("{}".format(user.id), self.channel_name)
            print(f"Add {self.channel_name} channel to post's group")
            print('connected')
    # @database_sync_to_async
    # def _get_user_group(self, user):
    #   if not user.is_authenticated:
    #       raise Exception('User is not authenticated.')
    #   else:
    #       print("user is not authenticated")
    #   return user

    async def disconnect(self,close_code):
        user = self.scope['user']

        await self.channel_layer.group_discard("{}".format(user.id), self.channel_name)
        print(f"Remove {self.channel_name} channel from post's group")
```

i'm not sure what exactly the mistake is

```
user is anonymous
    WebSocket DISCONNECT /like/ [127.0.0.1:50710]
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Please help.